# Move files in git from repo A to repo B/subdirectory without losing history

Tags: git

I have an assignment at university, and I have started developing for this in a git repository A. All the project's files are in the directory A/. However, I've just found out that as part of the hand-in process, we are requested to put the files in a repository B, under B/subdirectory/. At the moment, I don't have access to repository B - but the subdirectory has already been created by my lecturer.

What would be the best way to move the work I've already done to the subdirectory without destroying history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need access to repository B so that you can clone it

Then you can do a subtree merge so that repository A, can be moved to B/subdirectory.

Look here for more on subtree merge :  http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html

The steps given in the link above as example can be used for your scenario and should be pretty straightforward.